# Python Regular Expression for IP Address and URL

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, sys

I am trying to extract only the IP address and URL portion of a log containing data in the format of

```
153.12.123.123 - - [13/Nov/2014:15:06:43 -0700] "GET /icons/AHPS/0.06.png HTTP/1.1" 123 1234 "http://198.123.123.123/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/1234567 Firefox/33.0"

153.12.123.123 - - [13/Nov/2014:15:06:43 -0700] "GET /icons/AHPS/0.06.png HTTP/1.1" 123 1234 "http://abc.weatherabc.org/?Center=38.123456789" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/1234556 Firefox/33.0"
```

I currently am using this expression on the command line:

```
[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\"([^\"]*)\"
```

and it produces these as results:

```
http://198.123.123.123/index.html

http://abc.weatherabc.org/?Center=38.123456789
```

However I want a regular expression that produces only these portion:

```
http://198.123.123.123/

http://abc.weatherabc.org/
```

or

```
http://198.123.123.123

http://abc.weatherabc.org
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, your question is actually about removing parts from the URL?

Comment: Can't you use this? `http:\/\/[0-9a-zA-z\.]+`

Comment: How about `(?<=\")http[^\"]+(?=/)`? [Link](https://regex101.com/r/YsqivJ/1)

Comment: @David need to include hyphens too

Comment: @David it works, thank you!

Comment: @WandaW As stated by @PeterGibson, you need to include hyphens in that regex I gave before. Updated one: `http:\/\/[0-9a-zA-z\.\-]+`

Answer (score 0):

```
"(http://[^/]+)
```

Search for the keyword http which is common and end at the first /

- " Looks for "
- http:// This will match http://
- [^/]+ This will match all characters except /
- Brackets are used to extract required data which is why " is outside    brackets. This is called as groups.

If you need / at the end just add it to the group

```
"(http://[^/]+/)
```

Comment: Please provide an example as well, a little descriptive.